# What engineering concepts are used in EV3 programming/ a Mindstorms robot?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

If possible, could someone please compile a list of the engineering concepts associated with EV3 programming and Mindstorms robots.

Thank you - your answers are much appreciated.

Comment: That will depend on the problem or problems to be dealt with... So broad...

Comment: OK... what about a robot completing a maze?

Comment: And a general list of concepts is fine... then I can read the list to see which concepts are relevant to my project.

Comment: Is the maze in zero g ? then you have x, y and z to consider. Underwater? Why not define your project then we may be able to help... Is this a school project / competition?

Comment: @TBC "Completing a maze" is still far to vague. For example the "concepts" you need to detect where you are in a maze depend how the maze is defined. If it's drawn as neat rectangular lines on a table top, that is completely different from it is a 1 square kilometer outdoor terrain including bridges and/or tunnels to different levels (and including some "underground" sections with no natural light).